# Como mostrar o "diasSemana" que retornam no request?

Tags: javascript, react-native, app

Estou programando em *JS* para *React-Native* e não estou conseguindo exibir na `FLATLIST` dos dias da semana (serão nomes dos usuários mais para frente) que vem no Array.

```
class alunoAgenda extends Component {

        componentDidMount = () => {
            this.props.contatosUsuarioFetchDOIS()
        }

      render() {
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
                <FlatList
                data={this.props.diaSemana}
                renderItem={({ item }) => <Item key={item.id} {...item} />}
                keyExtractor={item => item.id}
                />
          </View>
        )

      }
    }
```

Código da Action contatoUsuarioFetchDOIS:

```
export const setTime = diaSemana => {
    return {
        type: SET_TIME_DOIS,
        payload: diaSemana,
    }
}

export const contatosUsuarioFetchDOIS = () => {
        return dispatch => {
            axios.get('https://my-rugby-fit.firebaseio.com/HorarioDoisVagas.json')
                .catch(err => console.log('não foi possível'))
                .then(res => {
                    const rawdiaSemana = res.data
                    const diaSemana = []
                    for (let key in rawdiaSemana) {
                        diaSemana.push({
                            ...rawdiaSemana[key],
                            id: key
                    })
                }

                dispatch(setTime(diaSemana))
            })
        }
 }
```

Comment: Qual a finalidade real desse for (let key in rawdiaSemana) {
      diaSemana.push({
       ...rawdiaSemana[key],
       id: key
      })
     }

Comment: qual o response desse get?

Comment: o GET retorna os objetos do Firebase em ARRAY pois a finalidade do for(let key in rawdiaSemana... transforma os objetos em array

Comment: Me manda o response pra eu simular a situação real sua